# How to treat skin corrosion by sodium hydroxide?

Tags: safety

I'm under training of becoming floorman in the rig. We use a lot of chemicals and one of them is caustic soda or sodium hydroxide. In case it touches my skin can you tell me of ways to treat it? I have thought of neutralizing it by slowly going less basic by using for example household ammonia then hand soap then sea water.

Comment: I suggest that you look on the web for the safety data for this any any other compounds you use. Sodium hydroxide will make the skin feel soapy. I would not use ammonia but wash with copious amounts of soap & water as soon as possible. Then wash again when you think you have removed it all.

Comment: I don't think you understand how neutralization works. Adding more base (ammonia) will not help you. As with most (but definitely not all) chemicals, the correct response is to flood the affected area with water immediately. You want to get it off you as quickly as possible, not go slow and add more base.

Answer (score 5):

> We use a lot of chemicals […]

1. **Before** you start to use potentially hazardous compounds and products, get their *Material Safety Data Sheets* (MSDS) and **read them**.
2. Learn about storage, handling, disposal and **emergency measures** in case of

   - eye contact
   - skin contact
   - inhalation

For a $50\%$ sodium hydroxide solution, a typical MSDS looks like [this](http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9924999) and states:

> **Skin Contact:**
>
> In case of contact, immediately flush skin with plenty of water for at least $15$ minutes while removing contaminated clothing and shoes. Cover the irritated skin with an emollient. Cold water may be used. Wash clothing before reuse. Thoroughly clean shoes before reuse. Get medical attention immediately.

**Forget about the ammonia!** Use lots of water!